# Por que não é possível criar uma variável denominada "tempo" no VisualG?

Tags: variáveis, visualg, syntax-error

Estou aprendendo lógica de programação e sei que existem algumas regras relacionadas à criação de variáveis, como pontuação, por exemplo. Sei também que no VisualG não se pode criar variáveis com palavras de comando ("ou", "e", "para", etc.).

Mas por um motivo que eu desconheço completamente, o VisualG não me permite utilizar palavra "tempo" como variável. Mesmo que ela não se enquadre em nenhuma das situações citadas no primeiro parágrafo... Aparece um erro dizendo que o programa "esperava o comando inicio", mas eu me certifiquei de que estava tudo correto, pois mudei para outra variável e deu certo. O código é extremamente simples, caso possam me esclarecer essa situação eu agradeceria.

```
    Algoritmo "algumnome"
Var
 tempo: inteiro
inicio
 tempo <- 5
 escreva(tempo)
fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sou entendido da linguagem, mas li tudo o que pude sobre ela, principalmente:

- https://www.acad.cefetmg.br/uploads/MATERIAIS_AULAS/340988-A_Linguagem_de_Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_do_VisuAlg.pdf
- https://visualg3.com.br/tabelas/

E mesmo a palavra tempo não constando nas reservadas, ainda sim existe a palavra `timer`, achei estranho o documento mostrar o uso de palavras que não estão em português, mas não é o único caso, então resolvi testar, conforme o documento:

> ### Comando Timer
>
> ... O comando `timer` serve para este propósito: insere um atraso (que
> pode ser especificado) antes da execução de cada linha. Além disso,
> realça em fundo azul o comando que está sendo executado, da mesma
> forma que na execução passo a passo.
>
> Sua sintaxe é a seguinte:
>
> | Comando | Descrição |
> | --- | --- |
> | `timer on` | Ativa o timer |
> | `timer<tempo-de-atraso>` | Ativa o timer estabelecendo seu tempo de atraso em milissegundos. O valor padrão é 500, que equivale a meio segundo. O argumento `<tempo-de-atraso>` deve ser uma constante inteira com valor entre 0 e 10000. Valores menores que 0 são corrigidos para 0, e maiores que 10000 para 10000. |
> | `timer off` | Desativa o time |

Então coloquei em prática a teoria, o `tempo` provavelmente é o próprio `timer` e com o código a seguir foi confirmando, nele o `tempo 2000` define que todos comandos irão ter um intervalo de 2 segundos:

```
Algoritmo "exemplo"

Inicio
tempo 2000
Escreval("Iniciou")
Escreval("Terminou após dois segundos")

FimAlgoritmo
```

Resultado:

[image: comando timer/tempo no VisualG]

Portanto o `tempo` e o `timer` provavelmente são a mesma coisa, pode ser um bug, ou esqueceram de documentar. VisualG usa uma linguagem próxima ao Portugol (ou talvez a própria variação). Nos testes que realizei cada interpretador tem sua própria variação da linguagem e parecem não tem compatibilidade alguma entre si (testei em 2 diferentes interpretadores, além do VisualG), o que me faz pensar que talvez `timer` e `tempo` tenha sido algo esquecido, mas só quem pode confirmar de fato algo são os desenvolvedores.